# How about the sortedArrayUsingComparator method do when I return NSOrderedSame in block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Let's see the code:

```
NSArray *array = @[@1,@3,@2,@5, @6];
NSArray *array2 = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

I know the usage of `return NSOrderedAscending` and `return NSOrderedDescending`. But if I write `return NSOrderedSame` in the block, whether the sequence of these two item won't be changed.

Comment: Did you tried yourself?

Comment: I tried, the sequence doesn't change.

Comment: Read this :[Sorting Arrays](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray#sorting-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know which sort algorithm is used in NSArray, you can go to this question: [What sort function is used in NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841445/what-sort-function-is-used-in-nsarray)

If you return NSOrderedSame in the sort block, the array will do nothing for all algorithms. :)

Answer (score 2):

It will say "oh that's cool" and it will move onto the next pair without moving the current pair and finish the sorting quickly as the array *appears* to be already sorted.

Of course, it's not actually sorted as you are lying to it:

> Garbage in, garbage out